# I'm running into this weirdness using the concept of certainty. Why?

Tags: logic, epistemology, knowledge

1. I cannot be certain of anything. (Assumption.)
2. I am not certain that I cannot be certain of anything.
3. By asserting (2), I am certain that I am not certain that I cannot be certain of anything.
4. I can be certain of something (3), therefore it's not the case that I cannot be certain of anything.

I can't spot my mistake... can you help?

Comment: Consider the language E-prime. The problem is that you're making predicates that are mutually incompatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption (1) is a certainty - it is so, by definition.

Therefore 2: 'I'm not certain that I cannot be certain of anything', is invalid.

Comment: Does this mean my assumption is false? I can assert that I can be certain of some things? Is this a reasonable dichotomy?

Comment: How can your assumption be false? You have made it an assumption - an **axiom**! There is no possibility to for it to be questioned.

Comment: Doesn't inconsistency mean that the assumption is not a reasonable assumption?

Comment: "the assumption is not a reasonable assumption" - Yet you assumed it anyhow, and built your house of cards upon it.  **'you can't have your cake and eat it too'** :-)

Comment: @user72273 you can _assume_ it, but, as you see, it leads to this problem. So it isn't a very good assumption, is it?

Comment: Premise: All of my thoughts may be deluded and false. I can't be certain that this isn't the case. Therefore, I am certain that I can't be certain that this isn't the case. Therefore, by contradiction, I have a bad assumption. Not all of my thoughts are deluded and false. Is this logical?

Comment: No, it is not: Again, according to your original premise, you can **never be certain of anything**. You are attempting to build certainty from a 'premise' of uncertainty. This cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the inference from (1) to (2) is valid. The problem I have with the argument is the transition from (2) to (3). I am going to rewrite the argument first:

1. Assume that it is impossible for me to be certain of the truth of any proposition.
2. From (1) it follows that I am not certain that *it is impossible for me to be certain of anything* is true.
3. From (1) and (2), I am certain that I am not certain that it is impossible for me to be certain of anything. (invalid)

Here is a less logicky example showing how (2) can be true while (3) false.

Suppose I think *all hippos are gray* is true, but (at first blush) I'm a little hesitant as I think that there might be some red hippos in a far away land. On the basis of this, we would say *I am not certain that "all hippos are grey"* is true. Does it follow that *I am certain that I am not certain that proposition that "all hippos are grey"* is true? No, for even if we assume that I am uncertain about whether all hippos are grey, I might *not be certain that I'm uncertain*. I might say to myself, "ya know? I thought I don't even know if I am uncertain. Maybe I am certain that all hippos are grey.

To make the argument valid. You need another premise that our knowledge of our own epistemic/mental states is always transparent to us.